# Buddha or Buddhism?

Tags: discussion

In several answers I can see people interpreting Buddha and giving references about masters other than Buddha. Is this forum about Buddha or Buddhism? Buddhism like Hinduism, Christianity and other religions is corrupted. For ex Buddha never prayed but lots of buddhist pray.

Comment: Is there a forum exclusively for Buddha?If not I would love to start one. I want to meet people who have benefitted from Buddha and can share experiences rather than just suttas or theology.

Comment: There is "area51" at stackexchange where one can create any new community.

Answer (score 2):

This site welcomes questions and answers about Buddhism: including all forms/schools of Buddhism.

On this site, it would also be also on-topic to ask about Buddhist history, culture, art, and so on -- but most questions are about theory and/or practice.

You can use various tags to limit the scope of your own questions. For example, some people regard Theravada as the school mostly closely based on the original (earliest) form of Buddhism, and if you add the [theravada](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theravada) tag to your question, that means you want to limit replies to answers that come from a Theravada perspective.

There's also a [the-buddha](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-buddha) tag, which is for, "questions about the Buddha (Siddartha Gautama) as a person - his life, sayings, actions, etc.".

On the other hand in [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/15013/254) you refer to obtaining a best answer by "asking a living Buddha".

---

**I want to meet people who have benefitted from Buddha and can share experiences rather than just suttas or theology.**

I encourage users to consider [these guidelines](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/):

> The folks ... owned up to the subjective issue and came up with a set of principles to create useful subjective discussions ...: the **Back It Up! Principle**. Back It Up! means that your answers must be based on either:
>
> - Something that happened to you personally
> - Something you can **back up** with a reference

So, answers shouldn't be based on a complete guess or lack of knowledge -- but this site does allow both, answers based on personal experience, and answers which give references (e.g. to suttas).

Comment: Living Buddhas are best source if you can find one. If you cant then scriptures are the best source but they are corrupted more often than not. Intelligence of a common man is quite less and therefore middlemen come in to explain Suttas. Simplification of Suttas for general public leads to corruption of Suttas. For example three percenpts or eight percepts or ten percepts are not Buddha's making but few who think that they understood Buddha. Buddha's path is that of intelligence and therefore meant for a small part of humanity. Unfortunately it was sold to everyone by good marketers.

Answer (score 1):

If I read you correctly, you are referring to drum sutta where Buddha explicitly said not to listen to teachings composed by other masters or teachers.  That is true however it is not easy to change other people's mind once they determine that teachings from other masters are worth learning.  There is Buddhist movement started about 10-15 years ago.  They exclusively study Buddhawajana (words from Buddha).  For myself, I'm inclined towards Buddhawajana movement.  I find that original Buddha's teaching are sophisticated but easy to understand.

Comment: i just want to point out the difference between Theravada and Buddhawajana Buddhism.  Theravada is " Doctrine of the Elders" where Buddhawajana is "Doctrine of Buddha".  It is possible that the "elders" might have added comments or explanation to the suttas, so in 2500+ years, things changes like you mention chanting in your question.  It is well accepted that Buddha did not chant but he recite laws of adhipajayadha (sic) [becuase this exists, that exists..etch or Pratītyasamutpāda ] when he was alone.

Comment: FYI [here were](http://www.dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?t=21616) some further descriptions/discussion of the Buddhawajana movement.

Comment: thanks Chris.  I'll check it out.

Comment: If Buddha recited few things that does not mean one start praying to Gods. In Thailand I was shocked to find temples having Hindu Gods and people praying to them the way Hindus do. Nothing wrong with praying but this path does not belong to Buddha. Buddha stressed on relying on individual effort. He never mentioned one can take help of dieties or celestial beings.

Comment: The fact is, the Buddha's own teachings were not written by the Buddha. They were written by students, or derived from other works which we know about (in particular, we can see shades of the Baghavad-Gita, Vedic scriptures, and elements of Taoist thought, without fully embracing anything). 

The Buddha didn't say "there are no gods", he said "the gods you can conceive aren't really gods" which could also imply: "the gods you can't conceive are the real gods" rather than there being any actual lack.

Comment: Prayers to these gods can in fact be appropriate, if we consider that they are not actually gods, but instead aspects of our own consciousness.